# MaaS & juju not provisioning in parallel

Tags: juju, maas

If juju is provisioning serially, how do I get it to provision multiple machines in parallel?  I can do 36 machine overnight (5 & 1/2 hours), but 1000 machine would, literally, take a week at the rate they are provisioning (9 minutes per machine).

I've asked about this before, and came away thinking it was done in parallel.  Multiple times over the last week, I have rebuild my juju environment from scratch and added 10s of machines to a charm:

```
juju add-unit -e maas octave -n 36
```

juju requests a single unit at a time from MaaS. MaaS brings it up, deploys the OS and hands it off to juju.  juju asks for another unit. It takes between 8 and 9 minutes to build each system and pass it off to juju.  It is very clear that this is being done serially, it looks like the culprit is juju, because it only requests one, but if I understood it that well, I wouldn't be having this problem.

```
Jun  3 01:19:52 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 12 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 01:25:14 MaaSServer maas.bootresources: [INFO] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
Jun  3 01:25:16 MaaSServer maas.bootsources: [INFO] Updated boot sources cache.
Jun  3 01:25:16 MaaSServer maas.bootresources: [INFO] Importing images from source: http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/releases/
Jun  3 01:25:17 MaaSServer maas.bootresources: [INFO] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
Jun  3 01:25:17 MaaSServer maas.import-images: [INFO] Started importing boot images.
Jun  3 01:25:17 MaaSServer maas.import-images: [INFO] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any new images.
Jun  3 01:25:23 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] useless-hospital.local: Stopping monitor: node-c31c2a14-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c
Jun  3 01:28:24 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 01:28:24 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 01:28:28 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 11 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 01:28:29 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'default']}>
Jun  3 01:28:29 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] sophisticated-ship.local allocated to user goober
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] sophisticated-ship.local: Starting monitor: {u'deadline': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 3, 1, 8, 30, 78690, tzinfo=<twisted.protocols.amp._FixedOffsetTZInfo object at 0x7fefc38d8150>), u'id': u'node-ec093070-ff29-11e4-9ab6-f0def14b3a7c', u'context': {u'node_status': 9, u'timeout': 2400.0}}
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for maas
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fefc6017cd0>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fefc6017cd0>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for 1.0.10.in-addr.arpa
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d2c39d0>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d2c39d0>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 01:28:30 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state (on) of node: sophisticated-ship.local (node-ec093070-ff29-11e4-9ab6-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 01:28:34 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changed power state (on) of node: sophisticated-ship.local (node-ec093070-ff29-11e4-9ab6-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 01:30:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 56 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 01:31:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 57 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 01:28:29 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 12 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 01:33:47 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] sophisticated-ship.local: Stopping monitor: node-ec093070-ff29-11e4-9ab6-f0def14b3a7c
Jun  3 01:37:00 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 01:37:00 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 01:37:05 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 11 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 01:37:05 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'default']}>
Jun  3 01:37:05 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] emotional-farmer.local allocated to user goober
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] emotional-farmer.local: Starting monitor: {u'deadline': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 3, 1, 17, 6, 540817, tzinfo=<twisted.protocols.amp._FixedOffsetTZInfo object at 0x7fefc38d8150>), u'id': u'node-b6832f28-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c', u'context': {u'node_status': 9, u'timeout': 2400.0}}
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for maas
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7b2a10>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7b2a10>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for 1.0.10.in-addr.arpa
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7b2590>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7b2590>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 01:37:06 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state (on) of node: emotional-farmer.local (node-b6832f28-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 01:38:27 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changed power state (on) of node: emotional-farmer.local (node-b6832f28-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 01:40:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 58 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 01:44:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 57 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 01:44:11 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] emotional-farmer.local: Stopping monitor: node-b6832f28-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c
Jun  3 01:45:03 MaaSServer maas.import-images: [INFO] Started importing boot images.
Jun  3 01:45:04 MaaSServer maas.import-images: [INFO] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any new images.
Jun  3 01:45:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 58 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 01:45:37 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 01:45:41 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 11 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 01:45:42 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'default']}>
Jun  3 01:45:42 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] frilly-quiet.local allocated to user goober
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] frilly-quiet.local: Starting monitor: {u'deadline': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 3, 1, 25, 43, 152292, tzinfo=<twisted.protocols.amp._FixedOffsetTZInfo object at 0x7fefc38d8150>), u'id': u'node-82659d48-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c', u'context': {u'node_status': 9, u'timeout': 2400.0}}
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for maas
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d5e0090>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d5e0090>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for 1.0.10.in-addr.arpa
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d355e10>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d355e10>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 01:45:43 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state (on) of node: frilly-quiet.local (node-82659d48-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 01:45:47 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changed power state (on) of node: frilly-quiet.local (node-82659d48-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 01:47:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 59 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 01:45:42 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 25 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 01:50:54 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] frilly-quiet.local: Stopping monitor: node-82659d48-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c
Jun  3 01:54:13 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 01:54:13 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 01:54:18 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 11 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 01:54:18 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'default']}>
Jun  3 01:54:18 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] quiet-garden.local allocated to user goober
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] quiet-garden.local: Starting monitor: {u'deadline': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 3, 1, 34, 19, 481105, tzinfo=<twisted.protocols.amp._FixedOffsetTZInfo object at 0x7fefc38d8150>), u'id': u'node-1da2d230-fe5d-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c', u'context': {u'node_status': 9, u'timeout': 2400.0}}
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for maas
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c752b50>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c752b50>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for 1.0.10.in-addr.arpa
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d2ee290>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d2ee290>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 01:54:19 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state (on) of node: quiet-garden.local (node-1da2d230-fe5d-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 01:55:48 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] quiet-garden.local: Power state has changed from off to on.
Jun  3 01:55:49 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changed power state (on) of node: quiet-garden.local (node-1da2d230-fe5d-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 01:56:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 60 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 01:57:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 59 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 01:59:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 60 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 02:02:50 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 02:02:54 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 24 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 02:02:55 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'default']}>
Jun  3 02:02:55 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] fine-bikes.local allocated to user goober
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] fine-bikes.local: Starting monitor: {u'deadline': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 3, 1, 42, 56, 67335, tzinfo=<twisted.protocols.amp._FixedOffsetTZInfo object at 0x7fefc38d8150>), u'id': u'node-f9cea154-ff29-11e4-9ab6-f0def14b3a7c', u'context': {u'node_status': 9, u'timeout': 2400.0}}
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for maas
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d1dc450>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d1dc450>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for 1.0.10.in-addr.arpa
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d1d9c50>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d1d9c50>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 02:02:56 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state (on) of node: fine-bikes.local (node-f9cea154-ff29-11e4-9ab6-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 02:03:00 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changed power state (on) of node: fine-bikes.local (node-f9cea154-ff29-11e4-9ab6-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 02:02:55 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 12 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 02:03:51 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] quiet-garden.local: Stopping monitor: node-1da2d230-fe5d-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c
Jun  3 02:05:03 MaaSServer maas.import-images: [INFO] Started importing boot images.
Jun  3 02:05:04 MaaSServer maas.import-images: [INFO] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any new images.
Jun  3 02:06:29 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_full_dns_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7f5c90>, <provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7f5950>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload'], False), 'upstream_dns': u'172.27.1.184', 'trusted_networks': u'10.0.1.0/24;'}
Jun  3 02:06:29 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload'], False) {}
Jun  3 02:06:29 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload'], False) {}
Jun  3 02:06:29 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_full_dns_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7f5c90>, <provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7f5950>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload'], False), 'upstream_dns': u'172.27.1.184', 'trusted_networks': u'10.0.1.0/24;'}
Jun  3 02:08:17 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] fine-bikes.local: Stopping monitor: node-f9cea154-ff29-11e4-9ab6-f0def14b3a7c
Jun  3 02:08:50 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_full_dns_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d3a7d10>, <provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d3a7d50>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload'], False), 'upstream_dns': u'', 'trusted_networks': u'10.0.1.0/24;'}
Jun  3 02:08:50 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload'], False) {}
Jun  3 02:08:50 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload'], False) {}
Jun  3 02:08:50 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_full_dns_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d3a7d10>, <provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d3a7d50>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload'], False), 'upstream_dns': u'', 'trusted_networks': u'10.0.1.0/24;'}
Jun  3 02:11:27 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 02:11:27 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>
Jun  3 02:11:31 MaaSServer maas.api: message repeated 12 times: [ [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'Loose']}>]
Jun  3 02:11:31 MaaSServer maas.api: [INFO] Request from user goober to acquire a node with constraints <QueryDict: {u'agent_name': [u'9224aee9-1f37-432f-8bfc-5a81b184c7d4'], u'zone': [u'default']}>
Jun  3 02:11:31 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] muddy-feeling.local allocated to user goober
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] muddy-feeling.local: Starting monitor: {u'deadline': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 3, 1, 51, 32, 862863, tzinfo=<twisted.protocols.amp._FixedOffsetTZInfo object at 0x7fefc38d8150>), u'id': u'node-936d0fe0-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c', u'context': {u'node_status': 9, u'timeout': 2400.0}}
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for maas
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d3a2310>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d3a2310>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for 1.0.10.in-addr.arpa
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7317d0>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 02:11:33 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 02:11:33 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 02:11:33 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7317d0>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 02:11:33 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state (on) of node: muddy-feeling.local (node-936d0fe0-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 02:11:37 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changed power state (on) of node: muddy-feeling.local (node-936d0fe0-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
^Cnrac@MaaSServer:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/maas/maas.log
[sudo] password for goober: 
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'maas'],) {}
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSForwardZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9d3a2310>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'maas'])}
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for 1.0.10.in-addr.arpa
Jun  3 02:11:32 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7317d0>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 02:11:33 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Starting task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 02:11:33 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'rndc_command' with args: ([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'],) {}
Jun  3 02:11:33 MaaSServer maas.calls: [INFO] Finished task 'write_dns_zone_config' with args: () {'zones': [<provisioningserver.dns.zoneconfig.DNSReverseZoneConfig object at 0x7fef9c7317d0>], 'callback': provisioningserver.tasks.rndc_command([u'reload', u'1.0.10.in-addr.arpa'])}
Jun  3 02:11:33 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state (on) of node: muddy-feeling.local (node-936d0fe0-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 02:11:37 MaaSServer maas.power: [INFO] Changed power state (on) of node: muddy-feeling.local (node-936d0fe0-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c)
Jun  3 02:14:04 MaaSServer maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 61 DHCP leases to region controller.
Jun  3 02:16:50 MaaSServer maas.node: [INFO] muddy-feeling.local: Stopping monitor: node-936d0fe0-fe5c-11e4-b47d-f0def14b3a7c
```

Comment: It is clearly juju that is at fault, as separately allocating a group of machines in MaaS, they are processed concurrently.